# What is the shortest way to assign different random lists to two variables?

Tags: python, list, variable-assignment, list-comprehension

What is the shortest way to get to two distinct lists, `a`, and `b`, which contain random integers.

I currently have:

```
(a,b)=([randint(0,30)for x in range(10)][randint(0,30)for x in range(10)])
```

or

```
a=[randint(0,30)for x in range(10)]
b=[randint(0,30)for x in range(10)]
```

Using

```
a=b=[randint(0,30)for x in range(10)]
```

produces two identical lists.

Is there a shorter way to do this?

Comment: Are you charged by the character? I'd *maybe* extract the list generation to a function and call it twice, but there's nothing terrible about your second version.

Comment: Where you say "produces two identical lists", you're misunderstanding what's going on.  The code produces ONE list, you just have two names referring to that one list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `random.sample`:

```
from random import sample

r = range(0,30)
a, b = sample(r, 10), sample(r, 10)
```

Comment: This isn't quite the same, as it samples *without* replacement.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes the assignment is the same, but the way those two lists are gotten is different (shorter).

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my point: the original version could create a list like `[29, 5, 29, ...]`, repeating a number within the ten, which this version cannot. It's not just a different *way*, but leads to a different *set of outputs*. The acceptance suggests that this isn't a deal breaker for the OP (or they haven't thought of it) but I thought it should be noted for other users with similar problems.